# Low mapping reads for RNA sequence

Tags: rna-seq, read-mapping

I am new to RNA sequencing analysis. I have RNA samples for bacteria for different treatment. I did contaminant filtration, remove adapters and checked fastQC report: attached below for one sample (fwd and rev) [image: fwd]. [image: reverse] After mapping with the reference genome using bbsplit but the mapping is only 0.62%.

Any help/suggestions highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well, when you looked at the sequences of some of your reads, what species did they BLAST to?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to swbarnes2 comment, I'd suggest a more systematic approach.

[Kraken2](https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/kraken2/index.shtml?t=manual) is a tool for metagenomic analysis of reads, though it can be hard to set up.

[mash screen](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-019-1841-x) is another method for metagenomic analysis, much easier to set up but noisier.

If you are dealing with contamination, treating your data as metagenomic might help.

Also, as always, ensure that your workflow and reference assembly are correct!!!